# RestKit working as Subproject but not as CocoaPod

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I was integrating RestKit as a subproject in XCode but just started using Cocoapods.  I had integration tests that passed without issue when RestKit was a subproject, but now after bringing it in through Cocoapods it doesn't appear to be making ANY requests.  Here is my basic test case:

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:args method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/users/auth/login" parameters:@{@"email": args.email, @"password": args.password}];

//requestOperation is always nil for some reason
[requestOperation start];
[requestOperation waitUntilFinished];
```

As stated above, the RKObjectRequestOperation returned from there is always nil, whereas before it would work as expected.  Here is the console output from the test:

```
2014-04-02 00:08:45.523 App[81180:90b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-04-02 00:08:45.526 App[81180:90b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000
Test Suite 'AppTests.xctest' started at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000
Test Suite 'AppTests' started at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000
Test Case '-[AppTests testLogin]' started.
/Users/matthewbaker/iOS/AppTests/AppTests.m:41: error: -[AppTests testLogin] : ((success) is true) failed - Login failed
Test Case '-[AppTests testLogin]' failed (0.001 seconds).
Test Suite 'AppTests' finished at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.001) seconds
Test Suite 'AppTests.xctest' finished at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.001) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-04-02 04:08:45 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.003) seconds
```

I'm used to seeing request/response output from RestKit here, but now there is nothing.

Comment: You shouldn't have `RestKit logging initialized...` twice. Did you remove the old installation? I assume `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` is now `nil`? Check your setup is being run.

Comment: @Wain ya, something was messed up in my working copy somewhere.  See my answer.  Thanks for your responsiveness on RestKit issues by the way, I'm sure I'll have many more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was badly messed up either in my project configuration as a result of pulling RestKit in through CocoaPods (maybe got put in a bad state), or in my local caches/build directories.  After pulling down a clean working copy and performing the CocoaPods integration again it started working.